# When applying "helm upgrade", ingress nginx says failed calling webhook. (details below)

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

UPGRADE FAILED: Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io": Post : x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

this is the exact error which comes when I am using helm upgrade.

tried to apply the previous local values file to helm upgrade. did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the following command fixed the problem. I am unable to find the root cause of the same

```
kubectl delete -A ValidatingWebhookConfiguration ingress-nginx-admission
```